# Regex: Identify file name with "string" but exclude if has .filepart extension

Tags: regex

I have a requirement to search through a directory to identify specific files with a string contained in the file name. But I want to exclude part loaded files with a ".filepart" extension.

This must be done through Regex due to tool limitations.

The file names can be in multiple formats, and we must identify them from the "file identifier" string that we pass into the Regex.

I have read some very good articles within SO and other websites but I am struggling to nail down the correct syntax.

I have saved a page on regex101.com to provide a more detailed explanation of what I am trying to achieve. The "FILETYPE" can be considered the string we pass into the Regex.

https://regex101.com/r/zTrbyX/4

Thanks,
K

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/zTrbyX/5 ?

Comment: One crucial character is all I was missing !! Thanks for correcting me @CAustin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original regex is:

```
.*FILETYPE.*\.[[:alnum:]]*(?!filepart)
```

will give the same result as:

```
.*FILETYPE.*
```

Instead you could use the following regex (similar to CAustin solution in comments):

```
.*FILETYPE.*(?<!filepart)$
```

This will match every line starting with `.*FILETYPE.*` and not ending with `filetpart`. Here `$` denotes the end of the line. In regex101.com you need to activate flag `m` for `$` to be recognized as EOL.

Comment: Works perfectly and removes unnecessary verbosity which I love. Thanks @Sergio.